# ERROR opencv_world310d.dll OPENCV - VISUALSTUDIO

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I get this error in opencv, I have reinstalled the same program ...
"The execution of Code can not continue because no opencv_world310d.dll was found. This problem can be fixed by reinstalling the program"
[image]

Answer (score 1):

copy the opencv_world310d.dll from the install directory to you visual studio project directory.

Comment: or add the opencv install path to the PATH environment variable

Comment: I work with multiple versions of visual studio and they have their own version of the DLL so this is not an option for me.

Comment: I was just adding an extra to your answer... the answer is correct, but some people may prefer just the environment path variable :)